# Edit CFM file in notepad

Tags: html, edit

I have downloaded and installed EveryonePrint.zip on everyoneprint.com
I like to edit some of their webpage files, these are saved in .cfm format.
When I open one of the files in notepad I only get symbols and numbers LIKE the following:

PK  oÏD               BDA[ó–µ¸ˆA2+±,±B/¹¨² $_/851'5Å?)+5¹ÄÎÌ

When the files are opened in a webbrowser and I click "Show source" i get HTML content.
How can I edit the files before the webbrowser converts it.

Is the file encrypted?

Here is one of the files: http://www.speedyshare.com/uNPRF/index.cfm

Comment: It's ColdFusion format, can't use notepad.

Comment: But What program should I use? No luck with Adobe ColdFusion Builder 3

Comment: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/filexc/f/cfmfile.htm May help you

Comment: It says: CFM files are 100% text based so any text editor, like Notepad, will properly show the contents of the file. But It's not

Comment: I've tried with notepad++ and it's readable.

Comment: But do you get all kind of symbols or HTML content?

Answer (score 0):

This CFM file (link above) in ZIP, enter into it using **Total Commander** (use Ctrl+PageDown key on file), and unpack source from it. Then edit source with an editor.

Comment: I get another files called BDA it says: í sr javax.crypto.SealedObject>